# Swift Module - When Importing I get "Redefinition of 'x' as different kind of symbol"

Tags: swift, cocoapods

While developing a swift Cocoapod we started seeing this error appear when importing it into other projects:

> "Redefinition of 'Category' as different kind of symbol"

There is a name spacing conflict in our module when it generates the Swift umbrella header

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research we found that you can refine how your umbrella header names classes

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35

Under "Configuring Swift Interfaces in Objective-C" section

> In some cases, you need finer grained control over how your Swift API is exposed to Objective-C. You can use the @objc(name) attribute to change the name of a class, property, method, enumeration type, or enumeration case declaration in your interface as it’s exposed to Objective-C code.

So this worked

```
@objc(YGCategory)
class Category: NSObject {
    //etc...
}
```